# npm install errors (setting up a react website template)

Tags: reactjs, terminal, react-chartjs

I get a compatibility error with react version of the project against my latest version when running the command **npm install**

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@hypnosphi/create-react-context, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/mini-create-react-context
npm WARN   mini-create-react-context@"^0.4.0" from react-router@5.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-router
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
npm WARN   node_modules/mini-create-react-context
npm WARN     mini-create-react-context@"^0.4.0" from react-router@5.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-router
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-chartjs-2@2.11.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=0.14.0" from @hypnosphi/create-react-context@0.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@hypnosphi/create-react-context
npm ERR!     @hypnosphi/create-react-context@"^0.3.1" from react-popper@1.3.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!       react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.7.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!         reactstrap@"8.7.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   7 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-router, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-chartjs-2@2.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-chartjs-2
npm ERR!   react-chartjs-2@"2.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-chartjs-2@2.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-chartjs-2
npm ERR!     react-chartjs-2@"2.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I ran the **npm install** command in the project directory.

Steps listed in the site below:

https://demos.creative-tim.com/blk-design-system-react/#/documentation/tutorial

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you're using react version 18.2.0 but react-router version 5.2.0 just support react version 17.0.0 backward.
Downgrade your react version to 17.0.0 or lower if you still want to use react-router version 5.2.0 otherwise update to react-router v6 for react v18 support